# Spoofing safe device identification in Android and Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, uniqueidentifier

We developed an Android application which acts like a simplified version of our webshop. Now we want to send a discount code to those who install our app.

We figured the following procedure would work:

When the app starts up the first time, the remote API is called to register the device using the FCM token. If this FCM token is new, we will send a push notification with the discount code.

This works, however, if the user re-installs the app it will create a new FCM token for the user so we will not be able to determine it is really the first time the user installs our app. Obviously we do not want a single user requesting multiple discount codes.

I understand that unique identifiers can be spoofed.

How can we solve this?

Comment: Use Firebase Authentication to get a unique id for each user who logs in, and remember those logins in a database.  FCM tokens not good for that.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that prior to sending the discount code you require user login. You can have a flag in the user database that indicates whether the specific user has received a discount, and if not, send it. Therefore, the token will be account, and not device specific.

The discount being device specific is not a good practise, since it may change owner. The new owner will not be entitled to a discount in this scenario.

Comment: We actually want to make it the user as simply as possible to purchase items, therefor we do not want to require the user to sign up for any acount. We actually deliver digital products so it isn't neccesary anyway. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: In my experience, uniquely identifying a device is hard. I know that this might not fit your requirements, but if I was to make this application I would have an option in the app saying "Sign up for free and receive X% discount". The sign up process can have several options, like using a Facebook or Google account. This can be completed in a few clicks, without having to set a password. Plus you get to have a larger user base. If this is something you would like, you can check how to achieve it here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Comment: That's actually a very good alternative idea. Thanks, we will consider this if it won't be possible without signing in.